# How to find data (specifically column name) which do not appear on both dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes (big enough). And they have columns: ch_name, time, values.
Now, df (first dataframe) has 160 channels but df1 (second dataframe) has 161 channels. How to identify channel name which excesses(df does not have this channel but df1 has). Sometimes channel names do not match between 2 dataframes. Finally I want 2 dataframes (separate) with same channel names and numbers. I want to make 160 channels for both dataframe. I do not want to join or concate them.

```
                        ch_name                time     value  interval
0     ADCS.Attitude_-_Omega_Y_deg_s 2019-01-05 00:00:00 -0.059533      60.0
1     ADCS.Attitude_-_Omega_Y_deg_s 2019-01-05 00:01:00 -0.063133      60.0
2     ADCS.Attitude_-_Omega_Y_deg_s 2019-01-05 00:02:00 -0.057533      60.0
3     ADCS.Attitude_-_Omega_Y_deg_s 2019-01-05 00:03:00 -0.053867      60.0
4     ADCS.Attitude_-_Omega_Y_deg_s 2019-01-05 00:04:00 -0.067067      60.0
...                             ...                 ...       ...       ...
1435             ADCS.RW3_MsmtValid 2019-01-05 23:55:00  1.000000      60.0
1436             ADCS.RW3_MsmtValid 2019-01-05 23:56:00  1.000000      60.0
1437             ADCS.RW3_MsmtValid 2019-01-05 23:57:00  1.000000      60.0
1438             ADCS.RW3_MsmtValid 2019-01-05 23:58:00  1.000000      60.0
1439             ADCS.RW3_MsmtValid 2019-01-05 23:59:00  1.000000      60.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test data:

df1=pd.DataFrame({"ch_name":["ch1","ch1","ch2","ch3"],"time":pd.date_range("2019-10-12",freq="min",periods=4),"value":[1,2,3,4],"interval":[60,60,60,60]})                                                                                
df2=pd.DataFrame({"ch_name":["ch3","ch1","ch5","ch3"],"time":pd.date_range("2019-10-11",freq="min",periods=4),"value":[10,20,30,40],"interval":[70,70,70,70]})                                                                            
df1

  ch_name                time  value  interval
0     ch1 2019-10-12 00:00:00      1        60
1     ch1 2019-10-12 00:01:00      2        60
2     ch2 2019-10-12 00:02:00      3        60
3     ch3 2019-10-12 00:03:00      4        60

df2

  ch_name                time  value  interval
0     ch3 2019-10-11 00:00:00     10        70
1     ch1 2019-10-11 00:01:00     20        70
2     ch5 2019-10-11 00:02:00     30        70
3     ch3 2019-10-11 00:03:00     40        70

Create a set/array for the common column names:

#ss=set(df1.ch_name) & set(df2.ch_name)
ss= np.intersect1d(df1.ch_name,df2.ch_name)

Create the new data frames:

new_df1=df1[df1.ch_name.isin(ss)]

  ch_name                time  value  interval
0     ch1 2019-10-12 00:00:00      1        60
1     ch1 2019-10-12 00:01:00      2        60
3     ch3 2019-10-12 00:03:00      4        60

new_df3=df2[df2.ch_name.isin(ss)]

 ch_name                time  value  interval
0     ch3 2019-10-11 00:00:00     10        70
1     ch1 2019-10-11 00:01:00     20        70
3     ch3 2019-10-11 00:03:00     40        70
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with set logic:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a1', 'ba1', 'b1', 'c1'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a1', 'gg', 'b1', 'c2'])

df
   a1   ba1 b1  c1

df1
    a1  gg  b1  c2
```

To remove columns in df1 from df:

```
df.drop(columns = set(df.columns) - set(df1.columns), inplace=True)
df
   a1   b1
```

Comment: `set(df.columns).intersection(set(df1.columns))` is another way, where the order of the sets wouldn't matter

Comment: If you want to find the column that exists in 1 but not the other, use `.symmetric_difference` on the sets. At this point, it's unclear to me what is outstanding in your issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merge?

I've created some bogus data to show you how it works.

```
        data1 = [['ch1','12:55',512],['ch2','12:57',516], ['ch3','12:57',420],
    ['ch4','11:48',433],['ch5','10:42',467]]

        data2 = [['ch1','12:55',511],['ch2','12:54',519],['ch3','12:51',720],
    ['ch5','10:45',497]]

        import pandas as pd

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=('ch_name','time','value'))
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=('ch_name','time','value'))

        dfResult = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ch_name', how='inner')

        print(dfResult)

          ch_name time_x  value_x   time_y  value_y
     0     ch1    12:55      512     12:55      511
     1     ch2    12:57      516     12:54      519
     2     ch3    12:57      420     12:51      720
     3     ch5    10:42      467     10:45      497
```

The key here are the parameters how='inner' and on='ch_name'. how='inner' is how you say you want the columns that appear in both dataframes and on = column_name is how you define the columns you want to match.

I hope it helps.

Comment: "I do not want to join or concate them." I would assume that merge is also in the list of things they don't want to do

Comment: Furthermore, time and values are not same. Channel name and number of channels must same in both dataframe

Comment: I forgot to print the result of merge. As you can see it keeps the duplicated columns, columns with _x comes from df1 and columns with _y comes from df2.  They asked to keep the results apart but under the same columns names.

Comment: I changed the data. As you can see you keep the values of your distinct dataframes, and it only prints the columns where the chanel names are coincidents.